# Adjust spacing between columns, bar chart

Tags: powerbi

Trying to fine-tune format of bar chart, POWER BI.  I have six columns, would like three groups of two bars each.  Original chart bunched all six columns into the center of the graph, with no spaces.  I made two placeholder columns and included them so that I have two columns/space/two columns/space/two columns.

All the columns are still bunched into the center of the graph, with a lot of wasted space on either side. Minimum Category width and Maximum size have no effect, and inner padding widens the columns only slightly.

How can I manually position columns along the x-axis?

Comment: Can you share a .pbix?

Comment: Sorry, no.  Too much proprietary data, and I'm not proficient enough to sanitize it.

Comment: Well this is not possible to answer. I can only suggest your x axis is a number so it is plotting a linear scale as opposed to a categorical one.